# Slide in images - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to make 7 of my "cards" img(s) slide in from the left to the center of the screen like they are now. I tried using:

```
function FetchCards() {
    $("#pack").css('margin-left', 0);
    $("#pack").css('margin-right', 0);
    $("#pack").animate({
        left: '-1000px'
    }, 'slow');
};
setTimeout(FetchCards, 7000);
```

But it's not working, not sure where I should declare the function "FetchCards", etc. Please help. Here is my current code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/L4wgzTDcV86tZK1eE23D?p=info

What I'm asking is where do I declare the function "FetchCards" and would my code work for making the images invisible until they slide in?

Comment: @AlienArrays No, I put it below my PHP.

Comment: in your example code inside plnkr there are a lot of error and i'm no sure that you can put PHP inside. - i think PHP echo a lot of image that have the same ID... ID must be unique inside the html. the id that you "#pack" isn't inside HTML

Comment: @Frogmouth Where are there errors and where can I upload my code to display it properly?

Comment: what about margin-left instead of left?

Comment: you not paste the php code... but the "generated" html from PHP.

Comment: sorry... my english is too bad. but... your example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/L4wgzTDcV86tZK1eE23D?p=info , not wokrs for me.

Comment: @Frogmouth It's ok, and yeah I will fix it soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function FetchCards() {
  $("#pack").css('margin-left', 0);
  $("#pack").css('margin-right', 0);
  $("#pack").animate({
    'margin-left': '-1000px'
  }, 'slow');
 }
setTimeout(function(){FetchCards();}, 7000);
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexShilman Do you know where I would declare the "FetchCards" function in my code?

Comment: It doesnt matter. All function declarations get hoisted to the top anyway.

Comment: Ok so how do I add the function to my img tag? When I try it doesn't display anything and says it was expecting a ; or ,

Answer (score 0):

see my example and tell me if it look like what you needed...
EXAMPLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/CAqE4/

JS:

```
function FetchCards() {
    $("#pack").css({
        'margin-left': 0,
        'margin-right': 0
    }).animate({
        left: '-=1000px' // -= subtracts the number of pixel
    },function(){
        //this function will be called after #pack animate
        $(/*IMAGE SELECTOR*/).fadeIn(); //insert the image selector
    });
};
setTimeout(FetchCards, 7000);
```

CSS:
Your image must have `display:none` in css.